# How to get most recent elasticsearch results using search API

Tags: api, search, elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch cluster and am trying to query it using the RESTful Search API. My query would return the oldest results but I wanted the newest so I added a range filter

```
curl -XGET 'https://cluster.com/_search' -d '{
  "from": 0, "size": 10000,
  "range" : {
    "@timestamp" : {
      "gt": "now-1h"   
    }
  }
}'
```

But I get the following error

```
"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query],.....Parse Failure [Failed to parse source.........Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]
```

I've tried using `@timestamp`, `timestamp`, and `_timestamp` as well for variable names but that didn't work. I've also confirmed that it is the range option that is causing the request to fail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not formatted correctly, you miss a "query" level:

```
curl -XGET 'https://cluster.com/_search' -d '{
  "from": 0, "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "range" : {
      "@timestamp" : {
        "gt": "now-1h"   
      }
    }
  }
}'
```